# Where do I place a code that when the form is submitted, it will redirect to another page?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following php code that has worked great. However, instead of after submitting the form and displaying "Thank you" on a page, I want it to be redirected to another page that i have designed beautifully. The page is labelled as thankyou.html.

Here is my php code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRaip.png)

Please where do I place the code for redirection to thankyou.html page?
Thanks
Zollyzo

Comment: can you paste te code in the image in your question?

Comment: Just a suggestion, you've got MySQL usernames/passwords in your screenshot as well as an open tab to a MySQL database with the URL in the title, you might want to replace out the login details (if they are the correct ones)

Answer (score 1):

The redirect code is `header("location:thankyou.html");`

If the insert query is executed, the page redirects to `thankyou.html`

```
if(mysqli_query($link,$sql))
{
    header("location:thankyou.html");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use

> `header('Location: thankyou.html')` or  `echo '<script>window.location.href
>   = "thankyou.html"</script>';`

in your if statement, 
you can use session to store temporary success message if you want to show some message after redirection